# Alternative function to Matlab's scatteredInterpolant for Python and C++ with given example

Tags: python, c++, matlab

I was wondering if anyone would know how to translate a function I have from Matlab to Python and C++. The main problem I have is to find an interpolation function equivalent to Matlab's [scatteredInterpolant](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html). I have searched for more information and found this other [entry](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12057/how-to-interpolate-scattered-data-to-a-regular-grid-in-python) but I have not been able to adapt the code, so I was wondering if anyone would know.

The **simplified** **Matlab** function would be as follows

```
function data_out = test_interp (data_input)
U = rand(20,20);
V = rand(20,20);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:20,1:20);
% Create matrix with specific format.
aux_array = [reshape(U,[],1) reshape(V,[],1) reshape(X,[],1) reshape(Y,[],1)];
% Apply scatteredInterpolant with vector arrays.
FX = scatteredInterpolant(aux_array(:,1),aux_array(:,2), aux_array(:,3));
FY = scatteredInterpolant(aux_array(:,1),aux_array(:,2), aux_array(:,4));
% Apply FX and FY to the desired input.
data_out(:,1) = FX(data_input(:,1),data_input(:,2));
data_out(:,2) = FY(data_input(:,1),data_input(:,2));
end
```

What it would do would be to perform the interpolation between two matrices and apply them to some input data, a way to call the function would be: `data_out = test_interp (rand(10,2))`

*I note the fact that the matrices are actually much larger and are not randomly generated, but they are useful to understand the effect.*

I was testing and in **Python** what I managed to do is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def test_interp (data_input):
    # Generate 
    U = np.random.random([20, 20])
    V = np.random.random([20, 20])
    [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(1, 20, 20), np.linspace(1, 20, 20))
    xx = griddata((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()),U.flatten(),(data_input[:,0],data_input[:,1]),method='linear')
    yy = griddata((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()),V.flatten(),(data_input[:,0],data_input[:,1]),method='linear')
    data_mm = [xx, yy]
    return data_mm
```

But from what I was seeing the griddata function is not well implemented, I also tried with np.interp2d but I didn't get the same thing.

With **C++** the same thing happens to me, I wouldn't know which function I should use to replace the Matlab function.

Comment: You're saying the griddata function is not well implemented. What exactly do you mean by that or more specifically what result did you get and what were your expectations? I don't own a matlab license so I can't compare on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @alexschu98. When I say "is not well implemented" what I mean is that I am using it incorrectly. What I need is to interpolate the data of the matrices (or vecectors) `U`, `V` to `X` and `Y`, that is, it would be to make (`U`,`V`,`X`) and (`U`,`V`,`Y`) and then apply to these interpolation vectors some data that will be matrices of as many rows as you want and 2 columns, the first will correspond to `x` and the second to `y`.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken but for me it looks like you are passing the arguments in different orders in each version. According to the docs `scatteredInterpolant(x,y,v)` takes `x, y` as points and `v` as surface data to interpolate. This means your matlab version has sample points at the positions `U,V`. `scipy.interpolate.griddata` also expects the points as first arguments but instead of `U,V` you pass `X,Y` here. So in Python you are making (`X`, `Y`, `U`) instead of (`U`, `V`, `X`) or at least that's what I am thinking right now.